# Accessing to Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
  <script>
    var url = document.URL;
    var mypage = /page=([0-9]*)/;
    var match = mypage.exec(url);
    if (match == null) {
      var next = url + "&page=2";
      var before = null;
    } else {
      var nextpage = parseInt(match[1]) + 1;
      var lastpage = parseInt(match[1]) - 1;
      res1 = url.replace(/page=[0-9]*/g, "page=" + nextpage);
      res2 = url.replace(/page=[0-9]*/g, "page=" + lastpage);
    }
  </script>
  <div class="mainbar"><div class="txt-vertical-align">something</div><a href=<%= res1 %> >link text</a></div>
```

My aim is to create an hyperlink, the url is stored in variable res1. However, the code I've posted does not do the job...

Comment: What is this `<%= res1 %>`, asp ? This is not how you set an element attribute value in JavaScript.

Comment: It is, yes, OP will have to use `createElement("a")` or set the href of that link through a Javascript selector.

Comment: It looks like handlebars, but I dont think this would work that way... Handlebars does not interpret your JS in your template, as it would be anightmare to sanitise user input...

Comment: You could actually do the following (although not recommended): `<a href="#" onclick="window.location = res1;" >link text</a>`

Comment: I second @ScottKaye, looks like this is JS, and he would need to put in the href via JS.

Comment: Either OP hasn't given us enough information, or he has a fundamental misunderstanding of how JavaScript interacts with HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...Once you build your `res1` variable, just assign it to the `a` href attribute with js

**Edited** put html before script declaration.

```
<div class="mainbar"><div class="txt-vertical-align">something</div><a href="#" id="MyLink" >link text</a></div>

<script>
 var url = document.URL;
 var mypage = /page=([0-9]*)/;
 var match = mypage.exec(url);
 if (match == null) {
   var next = url + "&page=2";
   var before = null;
 } else {
   var nextpage = parseInt(match[1]) + 1;
   var lastpage = parseInt(match[1]) - 1;
   res1 = url.replace(/page=[0-9]*/g, "page=" + nextpage);
   res2 = url.replace(/page=[0-9]*/g, "page=" + lastpage);

  //new code that sets href property
  document.getElementById("MyLink").href= res1; 

}
</script>
```

Comment: This wont work simply because of the order in which JS and code follow each other. Your node with that id doesn't exist yet.

Comment: The script is running before the element is created on the DOM and you keep the asp tags.

Comment: You know, you're right! I've bene jquery-ing for so long I didn't even think about that. Thanks!

Comment: @mituw Just remove the ASP code as well as its confusing and not necessary anymore. Also, jQuery _also_ has this problem, you just dont notice it because jQuery hides it! (If you do $("#myLink") without wrapping it in a `$(document).ready()` or a closure, it will return 0 objects and therefore not assign the `href` either, since jQuery cant read nodes that dont exists, just like pure JS)

Comment: You're correct in that jquery does have the same problem, it's just second nature to wrap everything in a `$(document).ready()` that I completely forgot about it. ;)

Comment: I do not understand what I should write in the HTML code

Comment: All you need to do is add an `id` to your link in your html so that javascript can easily find your link, then assign the link's `href` property.

Comment: I've writen `<div class="mainbar"><div class="txt-vertical-align">Sequentia Biotech Variant Query</div><a id="MyLink">link text</a></div>`, but it does not link anything...

Comment: Did you move your script declaration to after the html in the document? Also, check your browser console for any other errors that might be present.

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge there is no feature to bend javascript variables like <%= res1 %>

But I sujest you to study DOM API that you can access and manipulate properties of elements and nodes of HTML document.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

```
<a id='a-demo' href=<%= res1 %> >link text</a>
<script>
//This script should be after a tag
var url = "path";
document.getElementById("a-demo").href = url;
</script>
```

Feel free to comment.